# O que significa "Levar a mal"?

Tags: significado, português-brasileiro, expressões

O que significa "Levar a mal"?

Por exemplo:

> Eu lhe disse para não me levar a mal e me telefonar um dia qualquer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Significa *zangar-se*, *ofender-se*. É mais comum na negativa.

O *Dicionário Estrutural e Sintáctico da Língua Portuguesa* de Énio Ramalho tem estes exemplos:

> **levar a mal, não**:
>
> - podes estar tranquilo que ele não levou a  mal o que fizeste (não se zangou, não se melindrou);
> - não leves a mal o que disse o meu amigo, ele gosta muito de brincar (não te zangues, não te ofendas);
> - não leves a mal que eu te diga isso (não te melindres, não fiques zangado, não te aborreças);
> - eu não lhe levo a mal o não ter vindo à nossa festa, pois sei que tinha exame no dia seguinte (não estou zangado como ele; não fiquei melindrado);
> - afoitou-se a pedir-lhe que se tratasse em casa das pessoas tão suas amigas... que os pais não levariam a mal (não se zangariam, não poriam objecções, não ficariam melindrados.